# material ui edit autocomplete component dropdown style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

using material UI, Autocomplete component, it works fine but I need to edit style of expanded container, because its hiding footer,

As far as I see its because set position:"absolute", I see it in browser on inspect, but cant find in code.

```
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    // Dropdown container
    paper: {
      borderRadius: 0,
      boxShadow: 'none',
      border: '1px solid lightgray',
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
      top: -1,
      margin: 0,
      position: open ? 'relative' : 'position',
      width: '100%',
    },
    listbox: {
      maxHeight: 355,
    },
  })

  const classes = useStyles()
        
        ...
        
          <Autocomplete
            filterOptions={filterOptions}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(o: any, value: any) =>
              selectedOptions.find((op: any) => value.type === o.type && value.id === o.id)
            }
            onChange={(event: any, value: any) => handleAddUserGroup(value)}
            ListboxProps={{ id: 'list', role: 'list-box' }}
            ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
            disableListWrap
            open={open}
            defaultValue={selectedOptions}
            value={selectedOptions}
            disablePortal
            disableCloseOnSelect
            multiple
            id="user-groups-autocomplete"
            classes={{ ...classes }}
            forcePopupIcon={false}
            options={options.sort(
              (a: { type: any }, b: { type: string }) => -b.type.localeCompare(a.type),
            )}


enter code here


here how it covers footer; I want its heigth smaller when windows shorten respectively
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```